# Selenium + Phantom Error Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have the last version of Phantom 1.9.7 and Selenium WebDriver 2.41.
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prova.py", line 256, in <module>
html(IDs)
File "prova.py", line 65, in html
url = driver.get('http://srv00.ibbe.cnr.it/ASPicDB/resultsj.php?table=Protein&organism=human&accession=Hugo&gene_name=' + IDs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 178, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 166, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'Error Message => \'URL \'http://srv00.ibbe.cnr.it/ASPicDB/resultsj.php?table=Protein&organism=human&accession=Hugo&gene_name=ECHDC3\' didn\'t load. Error: \'ReferenceError: Can\'t find variable: organismChange\'\'\n caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"170","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:44380","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"url\\": \\"http://srv00.ibbe.cnr.it/ASPicDB/resultsj.php?table=Protein&organism=human&accession=Hugo&gene_name=ECHDC3\\", \\"sessionId\\": \\"8a3691a0-d1d8-11e3-a138-a164ac06a43a\\"}","url":"/url","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"url","directory":"/","path":"/url","relative":"/url","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/url","queryKey":{},"chunks":["url"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8a3691a0-d1d8-11e3-a138-a164ac06a43a/url"}' ;
```

Screenshot: available via screen

What it means? How can I fix it in Python?
Thanks

Comment: This seems to cause some problems `Can\'t find variable: organismChange`

Comment: And caused by Request => {"headers"...